# high order function. local var not referenced before

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on social network graph problem. The goal is to find the list of people N degree away from the target person. Target person id is 47

Data looks like `{(47,28):12,(47,15):13,(15,15):19,(15,47):6,(15,28):31,(28,16):67,(16,16):74 }`. The key pairs means two people know each other. Values doesn't matter here.

For example, when n = 1, the result expected is [28,15]

When running code below, got error "local var "opponent" not referenced before"

```
# Helper. 
# Input: [] of source people. 
# Output: [] of all who are friends with source people. 
# ! Contains duplicates and but not self. 
def opponent(data, source):
    opponent = []
    for s in source:
        for key in data: 
            if s in key:
                opponent.append(key ^ set([s]))
    return [next(iter(i)) for i in opponent if i]


def people_with_separation_number(data, n):
    if n == 0: 
        return [47]
    else: 
        source = people_with_separation_number(data,n-1) 
        opponent = opponent(data,source) 
        accum = [47]
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            seen = accum.extend(people_with_separation_number(data,i))  
        result = set(opponent) - (set(opponent)&set(seen)) 
        return result 

print(people_with_separation_number(data,0)) # expected answer [47]
print(people_with_separation_number(data,1)) # expected answer [28,15]
print(people_with_separation_number(data,2)) # expected answer [16]
```

Comment: again can someone explains to me why this is a bad question? i described the problem, i gave it a try myself. i got stuck and im here for help.

Comment: Since `opponent` is assigned to in `people_with_separation_number`, it is *local*. But you try to use it here: `opponent = opponent(data,source)`, because you've named your function `opponent`!  You can't use a local variable with the same name as a global variable. And even if this was all global, you don't  want to assign to a variable with the same variable as the function... Just use a different name. I didn't downvote, but this is probably getting downvoted because there are many many questions on this error and you dont seem to have researched it at all.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you. i didn't realize where to start look at the problem. but it's solved after your suggestion